# AES 128 encryption - Encryption in java and decryption in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, encryption

I have a code in Java in which encryption has been done as follows:

```
String encrypted = "mPgzvJKbSFgP6nRRHNlTufscZiChL2KUYaNeSF27+Dg=";
String key = "9d6ea4d3e6f8c4f8";
String salt = "1c5dd32d7ba54bdd"; 
String transform = "AES/CBC/ISO10126PADDING";

IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(salt.getBytes());
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transform);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);

byte[] encryptedBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encrypted); // hash to byte[] 
byte[] data = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes); 
System.out.println(new String(data));
```

Now, I need to decrypt it in javascript. The code I wrote is:

```
var key = '9d6ea4d3e6f8c4f8';
var iv  = '1c5dd32d7ba54bdd';

var options = {iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Iso10126};

alert("key + " + key);
alert("iv + " + iv);

var encrypted = 'mPgzvJKbSFgP6nRRHNlTufscZiChL2KUYaNeSF27+Dg=';
alert("encrypted + " + encrypted);
alert("encrypted.toString() = " + encrypted.toString());

var decrypyted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted.toString(), key, options );//error in this line.
alert(decrypyted);
alert(decrypyted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

The encryption is working properly and when I try decrypting the encrypted string using javascript, I am getting an error. The JS stops working once I execute the decrypt function. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: What's the problem? What happens when you try you code? Where (if at all) does it fail? How? Without knowing that, there's not much we can all do to help...

Comment: Um, your Java code looks like it's decrypting, not encrypting...

Comment: I have updated the problem statement.Please let me know if I need to add more details.

Comment: Please add to your question, what error you're getting.

Comment: To elaborate on Jon Skeet's remark, look at the top code block "encryption in java".  The question says this is "encryption".  But, the cipher.init() is passed Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE.  This looks suspicious. Perhaps, though, the top block shows that Java can decrypt data that is encrypted in `String encrypted`.  user3132417, could you click "edit" underneath your question and clarify this?